# How to change bitnami postgresql helm chart configs? (ph_hba.conf, postgresql.conf)

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, bitnami, postgresql.conf

How do you update postgresql.conf or pg_hba.conf for the main postgresql chart on https://artifacthub.io? (In particular I have been trying to update the wal_level within the postgresql.conf)

Related Links:

- https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/postgresql
- https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/postgresql
- https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/6830

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `values.yaml` with the following content

```
primary:
  extendedConfiguration: |-
    wal_level = logical
```

you can easily override only the `wal_level`

```
helm install my-postgresql bitnami/postgresql -f values.yaml
```

Answer (score 4):

Documentation is hard to follow without any real good examples, but basically in the fine print they mention you have to completely override postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf if you want to update anything here. I'm sure there is a better way to perform an update of just one key such as wal_level, but I found this approach to be the best at the moment.

Copy this yaml into a file (/path/to/this/file/values_bitnami_pg_postgresql_conf.yaml) and use if when you install the chart. This yaml contains all of the keys I found possible to edit at time of writing.

```
primary:
  # Override default postgresql.conf
  configuration: |-
    # Note: This configuration was created with bitnami/postgresql default chart, connecting and running `SHOW ALL;`
    #       then modifying to the appropriate yaml format. All values in SHOW present and if commented, this likely
    #       indicates attempt to set value failed. Please experiment. 
    #
    #       CHART NAME: postgresql
    #       CHART VERSION: 11.0.4
    #       APP VERSION: 14.1.0
    #       Example use: 
    #       >>> helm install pg-release-1 bitnami/postgresql -f /path/to/this/file/values_bitnami_pg_postgresql_conf.yaml
    #       (chart should display connection details... connect using psql and run `SHOW ALL;`)
    #       If anything appears odd or not present review the pod logs (`kubectl logs <target pod for release>`)
    allow_system_table_mods = 'off' #Allows modifications of the structure of system tables.
    application_name = 'psql' #Sets the application name to be reported in statistics and logs.
    archive_cleanup_command = '' #Sets the shell command that will be executed at every restart point.
    archive_command = '(disabled' #Sets the shell command that will be called to archive a WAL file.
    archive_mode = 'off' #Allows archiving of WAL files using archive_command.
    archive_timeout = '0' #Forces a switch to the next WAL file if a new file has not been started within N seconds.
    array_nulls = 'on' #Enable input of NULL elements in arrays.
    authentication_timeout = '1min' #Sets the maximum allowed time to complete client authentication.
    autovacuum = 'on' #Starts the autovacuum subprocess.
    autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = '0.1' #Number of tuple inserts, updates, or deletes prior to analyze as a fraction of reltuples.
    autovacuum_analyze_threshold = '50' #Minimum number of tuple inserts, updates, or deletes prior to analyze.
    autovacuum_freeze_max_age = '200000000' #Age at which to autovacuum a table to prevent transaction ID wraparound.
    autovacuum_max_workers = '3' #Sets the maximum number of simultaneously running autovacuum worker processes.
    autovacuum_multixact_freeze_max_age = '400000000' #Multixact age at which to autovacuum a table to prevent multixact wraparound.
    autovacuum_naptime = '1min' #Time to sleep between autovacuum runs.
    autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = '2ms' #Vacuum cost delay in milliseconds, for autovacuum.
    # won't let me post entire show ... so cut the middle 
    # ...
    vacuum_defer_cleanup_age = '0' #Number of transactions by which VACUUM and HOT cleanup should be deferred, if any.
    vacuum_failsafe_age = '1600000000' #Age at which VACUUM should trigger failsafe to avoid a wraparound outage.
    vacuum_freeze_min_age = '50000000' #Minimum age at which VACUUM should freeze a table row.
    vacuum_freeze_table_age = '150000000' #Age at which VACUUM should scan whole table to freeze tuples.
    vacuum_multixact_failsafe_age = '1600000000' #Multixact age at which VACUUM should trigger failsafe to avoid a wraparound outage.
    vacuum_multixact_freeze_min_age = '5000000' #Minimum age at which VACUUM should freeze a MultiXactId in a table row.
    vacuum_multixact_freeze_table_age = '150000000' #Multixact age at which VACUUM should scan whole table to freeze tuples.
    #wal_block_size = '8192' #Shows the block size in the write ahead log.
    wal_buffers = '256kB' #Sets the number of disk-page buffers in shared memory for WAL.
    wal_compression = 'off' #Compresses full-page writes written in WAL file.
    wal_consistency_checking = '' #Sets the WAL resource managers for which WAL consistency checks are done.
    wal_init_zero = 'on' #Writes zeroes to new WAL files before first use.
    wal_keep_size = '128MB' #Sets the size of WAL files held for standby servers.
    wal_level = 'logical' #Sets the level of information written to the WAL.
    wal_log_hints = 'off' #Writes full pages to WAL when first modified after a checkpoint, even for a non-critical modification.
    wal_receiver_create_temp_slot = 'off' #Sets whether a WAL receiver should create a temporary replication slot if no permanent slot is configured.
    wal_receiver_status_interval = '10s' #Sets the maximum interval between WAL receiver status reports to the sending server.
    wal_receiver_timeout = '1min' #Sets the maximum wait time to receive data from the sending server.
    wal_recycle = 'on' #Recycles WAL files by renaming them.
    wal_retrieve_retry_interval = '5s' #Sets the time to wait before retrying to retrieve WAL after a failed attempt.
    #wal_segment_size = '16MB' #Shows the size of write ahead log segments.
    wal_sender_timeout = '1min' #Sets the maximum time to wait for WAL replication.
    wal_skip_threshold = '2MB' #Minimum size of new file to fsync instead of writing WAL.
    wal_sync_method = 'fdatasync' #Selects the method used for forcing WAL updates to disk.
    wal_writer_delay = '200ms' #Time between WAL flushes performed in the WAL writer.
    wal_writer_flush_after = '1MB' #Amount of WAL written out by WAL writer that triggers a flush.
    work_mem = '4MB' #Sets the maximum memory to be used for query workspaces.
    xmlbinary = 'base64' #Sets how binary values are to be encoded in XML.
    xmloption = 'content' #Sets whether XML data in implicit parsing and serialization operations is to be considered as documents or content fragments.
    zero_damaged_pages = 'off' #Continues processing past damaged page headers.
  # Override default pg_hba.conf
  pgHbaConfiguration: |-
    # WARNING! This is wide open and only for toy local development purposes.
    # Note: To verify this is loaded, connect via psql and run `table pg_hba_file_rules ;`
    host     all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
    host     all             all             ::/0                    trust
    local    all             all                                     trust
    host     all             all        127.0.0.1/32                 trust
    host     all             all        ::1/128                      trust
```

Answer (score 1):

John's answer is correct and I found it very useful. I can add an alternative arrangement. If you want to avoid having the whole Postgres config in your `values.yaml` you can define it in a separate ConfigMap instead.

Create file postgresql-config.yaml in the templates folder:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgresql-configmap
data:
  pg_hba.conf: |-
    local  all        all                     scram-sha-256
    host   all        all       127.0.0.1/32  scram-sha-256
    host   all        all       ::1/128       scram-sha-256
    # and so on

  postgresql.conf: |-
    allow_in_place_tablespaces             = off
    allow_system_table_mods                = off
    archive_cleanup_command                = ''
    archive_command                        = ''
    autovacuum                             = on
    autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor        = 0.1
    # and so on
```

Then in your `values.yaml` file you only need:

```
postgresql:
  primary:
    existingConfigmap: "postgresql-configmap"
```

I really struggled finding information on how to define the ConfigMap but from looking at other bitnami tutorials I found it is key/values for `filename: file content`.